# sendMultipartTextMessage ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendMultipartTextOnSubscription NullPointerException

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

Im getting nullpointerexception for the following code:

I have SMS of more than 160 characters length, so im dividing them using divide() and then adding one sent PendingIntent.

Sometimes this exception comes up. My mobile number and sms data are not null;

```
   String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    BroadcastReceiver sentSMSStatusReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                   //TOAST
            }
            unregisterReceiver(this);
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(sentSMSStatusReciever, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    // since message is greater than 160 chars
    ArrayList smsContructedList = smsManager.divideMessage("SMS Content goes here ....");

    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPIList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(1);

    sentPIList.add(sentPI);

    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage("Mobile Number goes here", null,
            smsContructedList, sentPIList, null);
```

LOGS:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4527):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4527):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4527):    at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendMultipartTextOnSubscription(ISms.java:1351)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4527):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(SmsManager.java:354)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this:

```
ArrayList<String> messageArray = smsManager.divideMessage(myMessage);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
for (int i = 0; i < messageArray.size(); i++)
sentIntents.add(sentPI);
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(sendTo,null,messageArray,sentIntents, null);
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to add (sentIntents) pending intent list of the size of messageArray list?

Comment: Would I need the same for deliveryIntents?

Comment: Great answer! Helped me in 2020. I was trying to send sms via sendMultipartTextMessage. And all was working fine on almost all devices, except some Huawei tablets. Adding list of sent and deleivery PendingIntent to that call helped me.