# Android : SMSManager - Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I have a bug from the SMSManager when I try to send a message with the method `sendTextMesasge`. It returns me a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`.

There is my code :

```
        // Constructs the message
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     
        String myPhoneNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
        String destNumber = taskManager.getHelpCenterNumber();
        String message = getResources().getString(R.string.call_me_message) + " " + myPhoneNumber+".";

        // Sends the message
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(destNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

The LogCat receives this message :

```
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825): Process: com.solarsquareretailer.view, PID: 19825
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:1428)
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:305)
08-03 09:59:10.548: E/AndroidRuntime(19825):    at com.solarsquareretailer.view.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:245)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my destNumber was null and not correct (Not a phone number). It's why I have a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this several of times in my app in the wild (but never on my tests), and tried to find a solution for months. So far I could not find a test case that reproduces it.

Using the [Sms.sendMultipartTextMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultipartTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E)) method:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(msg);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, null, null);
```

Does not help either - as internally it ends up calling sendTextMessage if the message has only one part - but anyway, it might be a good idea if you switch to it just in case you have longer messages.

I ended up wrapping the code in a try-catch and reporting to a server whenever it happens. And from what I've seen, seemingly 'normal' messages seem to trigger it.

There is a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597804/sendmultiparttextmessage-ismsstubproxy-sendmultiparttextonsubscription-nullpoi), but in that case the message has a PendingIntent for sent. You might want to try that.

Comment: I try your method to check where is the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

First , you need  permission in AndroidManifest.xml for read Phone State

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Then try to get Mobile Number of Device in Try Catch Block .

It may happen that getLine1Number() return null value .
So you need to handle exception

```
try 
{
    myPhoneNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}
catch(NullPointerException ex)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have this line on my AndroidManifest.